# preimage definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

I'm currently studying functional analysis and the professor covered continuity using the definition that the preimage of every open set is open. I can follow the definition, which basically means showing that $\mathscr f^{-1}((a,b))$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$. The example he showed us was with  $\mathscr f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ but he did 2 lines of it and said it was trivial and I'm not particularly good at picking up things unless examples are shown :(, can someone break down how this definition is applied in a proof such as this one? dumbing it down a little would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=(a,b)$ be any open interval in $\Bbb R$; we need to figure out what $f^{-1}[I]$ is. By definition

$$\begin{align*}
f^{-1}[I]&=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2\in I\right\}\\
&=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2\in(a,b)\right\}\\
&=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:a<x^2+y^2<b\right\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is the union of the sets

$$C_r=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=r\right\}$$

for $r\in I$, i.e., for $a<r<b$. You should recognize $C_r$ as the graph of the circle of radius $r^{1/2}$ centred at the origin. Of course that makes sense only if $r\ge 0$, which is no surprise, since $x^2+y^2$ is never negative.

Now we need to consider three cases. If $a\ge 0$, then every $r\in(a,b)$ is positive, and $f^{-1}[I]$ is the union of the circles $C_r$ whose radii are strictly between $a^{1/2}$ and $b^{1/2}$; that set is an open [annulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29) (or washer) — open because it does not include the boundary circles with radii $a^{1/2}$ and $b^{1/2}$. If $p=\langle x,y\rangle$ is any point on the circle $C_r$, where $a<r<b$, you should check that the open ball centred at $p$ of radius $\min\{r^{1/2}-a^{1/2},b^{1/2}-r^{1/2}\}$ is contained entirely within the annulus. Thus, every point of $f^{-1}[I]$ is the centre of an open ball lying entirely inside $f^{-1}[I]$, which is therefore by definition an open set.

Now suppose that $a<0<b$. Then $C_r$ is empty for all $r$ such that $a<r<0$, so $f^{-1}[I]$ is actually the union of the circles $C_r$ with $0\le r<b$. You should have little difficulty checking that in this case $f^{-1}[I]$ **is** the open ball of radius $b^{1/2}$ centred at the origin and therefore is open.

Finally, suppose that $b\le 0$; then $r<0$ for every $r\in(a,b)$, so $f^{-1}[I]=\varnothing$, which is open.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f^{-1}(k)$ is a circle of radius $\sqrt k$ for any positive $k$. So $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is an open annulus, centered at origin, with in-radius $\sqrt a$ and out-radius $\sqrt b$, and you can show that this  set is open using the definition of open set. Take a point $x$ in the annulus and suppose $$\delta=\frac{\min \lbrace||x||-a,b-||x||\rbrace }{2} $$ then $B_\delta(x)$ is contained in the annulus.

Answer (score 0):

What you requested was already done in the two answers already posted. But one never needs to do that. Because what you have to show is that $(x,y)\mapsto x$, $(x,y)\mapsto y$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$, and $t\mapsto t^2$ are continuous, and that a composition of continuous functions is continuous.